# Jquery Scroll and Hover Glitch

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, hover

I have a div (.dock) fixed to the top of the page. When I scroll down vanishes and reappears when scrolled to the top. That works fine. To bring the dock into view later on down the page the user is able hover over the menu bar (.hover-dock). This hover function should only happen after the > 200 scroll.

This works initially but when scrolling back to the top the hover function becomes active causing confusion when the dock should well... remain docked. What am I doing wrong here? Here is my code...

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

if ($(this).scrollTop()>200)
 {
    $('.dock').hide();
    $('#sticky-nav').css('padding-top', '30px');
    $('.feed').css('margin-top', '30px');



//Push down the filter and feed
$('.hover-dock').hover(function(){
    $('.dock').show();
    $('#sticky-nav').css('padding-top', '125px');
    $('.feed').css('margin-top', '125px');
}, function(){
    $('.dock').hide();
    $('#sticky-nav').css('padding-top', '30px');
    $('.feed').css('margin-top', '30px');
}); 



 }
else if ($(this).scrollTop()<200)
 {
  $('.dock').show();
  $('#sticky-nav').css('padding-top', '125px');
  $('.feed').css('margin-top', '125px');
 } 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would have done it like this. Appending hover handler outside the `scroll()` function. And add a flag in order to know if `scrollTop()` is over or under 200px while hovering.

```
var top = true;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('.dock').fadeOut();
        $('#sticky-nav').css('padding-top', '30px');
        $('.feed').css('margin-top', '30px');
        top = false;
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
        $('.dock').fadeIn();
        $('#sticky-nav').css('padding-top', '125px');
        $('.feed').css('margin-top', '125px');
        top = true;
    }
});

//Push down the filter and feed
$('.hover-dock').hover(function () {
    if (top == false) {
        $('.dock').fadeIn(100);
        $('#sticky-nav').css('padding-top', '125px');
        $('.feed').css('margin-top', '125px');
    }
}, function () {
    if (top == false) {
        $('.dock').fadeOut(150);
        $('#sticky-nav').css('padding-top', '30px');
        $('.feed').css('margin-top', '30px');
    }
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a3dFw/)**